# copy shape Type = msoTextBox and then paste

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to convert a textbox shape into an image using VBA with Word. I cannot find how to do this with VBA and when I try and record a macro I cannot select the Textbox. The code I am using to find the text box is a reverse search of the shapes collection with a filter to only select if a textbox and then return the shape index number. My initial thoughts were to simply cut the shape and paste back as an image

Any suggestions most welcome

Comment: How do you do it manually - what are the steps? Can you record a macro if you *first* select the Textbox, then perform these actions? If yes, do that, use the [edit] link to include that in the question, along with the problems you encounter when trying to adapt the macro to be a useful tool (to get it to do what you need).

Answer (score 0):

When I attempt to do it manually and record a macro I am unable to select the shape. This is behaviour I have never encountered before. Using the following code I was able to copy the desired shapes. However the aspect ratio of resultant images changed and text was truncated for the type = msoTextBox. The Groups worked fine.
[VBA]
    Sub ShapeCopy()

```
Dim i As Integer, Shp As Shape

' Select last to first to retain shape numbering
' when shapes are deleted
For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
  Set Shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
  Shp.Select
  If Shp.Type = msoTextBox _
  Or Left(Shp.Name, 5) = "Group" Then

    Selection.Cut
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[/VBA]